# ADsDSOObject query: Columns available when querying the LDAP?

Tags: sql, vbscript, active-directory, ldap

I am writing a VBScript to query ADsDSOObject, and I don't quite understand the structure of the LDAP. I see how to find the available virtual tables in Active Directory, but I can't find where to look for the available virtual columns.

Also, if I "SELECT * FROM", it only returns the ADsPath.  I'd like to select more than just "Name", "Type", and "Description" from the objectClass='Computer' group.

```
Dim objCompArr
Dim currcomp
objCompArr = Array()
currcomp = -1

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set objCOmmand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM 'LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com' WHERE objectClass = 'Computer'"
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

If Not objRecordSet.EOF Then
    objRecordSet.MoveFirst
    Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
        currcomp = currcomp + 1
        ReDim Preserve objCompArr(currcomp)
        objCompArr(currcomp) = objRecordSet.Fields("Name")
        objRecordSet.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easiest to visually browse AD with an LDAP browser beforehand (like [the one from Softerra](http://www.ldapbrowser.com/), [ADSIEdit from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354%28WS.10%29.aspx) or [Active Directory Explorer from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907)).

You will be able to see all available properties on an object there and craft your query accordingly.

Surname is called `sn` for example, first name is `givenName`, the login is `sAMAccountName`, just to name a few.

You can always query for properties that are not set (or not even defined). This is not an error, as LDAP is designed to be extensible and not every property is defined on every object. You just will get empty columns as a result.

Comment: I think the problem is that the list of attributes on the Miscrosoft's ADs library show all attributes under every class, so, thinking the opposite was true, I queried for "Desktop-Profile" under  the class name "Computer" and got an error.  The same happens when I query for sAMAccountName.

Comment: @Dexter: What error? It might be that the SQL syntax has this side effect, personally I use [proper LDAP queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187529) [see also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746385(v=vs.85).aspx). Also I think that a dash is illegal in an LDAP property name.

Comment: It's just a "Generic Error" on line 15.  I got the property name from the Microsoft library I listed in my answer above.  But using the AD Explorer, I can see that it's not actually a property of computers.  There doesn't seem to be any property of Computers that shows me the active login, and no properties of User show the computer they're logged into.  It seems like I remember seeing a list of computers and their current users somewhere in AD or something, but it's been a while... It just seems like to me that if you have users logging in through the domain controller, that info would exist.

Comment: @Dexter: For the record, see also [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746385(v=vs.85).aspx) on alternative ADSI usage and this one on [the LDAP filter syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Ah, thanks I found it.  Now I'm just getting "Access denied", so I'll just need to add my login to the query.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Dexter: No, AFAIR there is no property that shows the active machine of any given user. There is a property "lastLogon", which is a timestamp. But it is not necessary replicated through domain controllers, so you'd have to ask every domain controller specifically and take the last date.